# Why does it keep returning false?

Tags: java

I tried my best to return int number as a perfect cube without declaring it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The assignment:     TODO: Return true if number is a perfect cube, false otherwise. You can assume the value
          of number is between 1 and 1000000

Note: a perfect cube is a number whose cube root is an integer

```
   static boolean Q1(int number) {
    int a = number/9;


    if(number==(a*a*a))
    {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
    // TODO: Return true if number is a perfect cube, false otherwise. You can assume the value
    //       of number is between 1 and 1000000
    //
    // Note: a perfect cube is a number whose cube root is an integer




}






ERROR:

-- Q1 --
Incorrect on input: 8
Expected output : true
Your output     : false
```

Comment: `int s = number/3;` is doing integer division e.g. `1/2 == 0`  try `double s = number/3.0`

Comment: The does not work.

Comment: The assigned so called duplicate question has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Your formula is wrong. Dividing a number by 9 doesn't produce a cube root, except for 27.

Comment: in addition think about the maths - do the calc on paper

Comment: so why close it ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat You can only say integer division is wrong in the context of the problem and solution. If we were trying to find a number evenly divisible by 3, integer division could make perfect sense. Since OP's solution has little to do with the problem, it's hard to pass judgement on a detail of it.

Comment: re-opened this question

Comment: Why would the cuberoot be `number / 9` ?  There are only three integers for which this is true.

Comment: @shmosel or -27 or 0.

Comment: `Incorrect on input: 8` so `8 / 9 == 0` `8 != 0 * 0 * 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
int s = number/3;
int a = s/3;
```

So a is now number/9

```
if( number==(a*a*a))
```

And here you check whether number is equal to `(number*number*number)/729`.
How is that supposed to mean anything?

You really need to figure out your algorithm before you start to code a single line.